# sort a pushed array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb result like this.

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "57174838afb8eb97ccd409ca",
      "name": "Yet another position",
      "description": "description",
      "code": "11Y-WK"
    },
    "votes": [
      {
        "candidate": {
          "_id": "56f19694e84a6bf1b66ad378",
          "surname": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "firstName": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "middleName": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "othername": " XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX",
          "sc_number": "071050"
        },
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "candidate": {
          "_id": "56f19690e84a6bf1b66aa558",
          "surname": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "othername": "XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX",
          "sc_number": "034837"
        },
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "candidate": {
          "_id": "56f19690e84a6bf1b66aa2f3",
          "surname": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "othername": "XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX",
          "sc_number": "008243"
        },
        "count": 4
      }
    ],
    "total_count": 9
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "_id": "571747a8afb8eb97ccd409c7",
      "name": "Test Position",
      "description": "Description",
      "code": "10T-9K"
    },
    "votes": [
      {
        "candidate": {
          "_id": "56f19690e84a6bf1b66aa3b7",
          "surname": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "othername": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "sc_number": "044660"
        },
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "candidate": {
          "_id": "56f19690e84a6bf1b66aa6ea",
          "surname": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "othername": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "sc_number": "062444"
        },
        "count": 5
      },
      {
        "candidate": {
          "_id": "56f1968fe84a6bf1b66aa03e",
          "surname": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "othername": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "sc_number": "042357"
        },
        "count": 3
      }
    ],
    "total_count": 9
  }
]
```

I need to sort by `count` in descending order.

Below is the query that returns the result above.
I've tried applying sort at all stages but with no luck.

```
  Vote.aggregate([
{ "$match": { "_poll" : mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.query._poll) } },
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "_position": '$_position',
      "candidate": '$candidate'
    },
    "voteCount": { "$sum": 1 }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._position",
    "votes": {
      "$push": {
        "candidate": "$_id.candidate",
        "count": "$voteCount"
      }
    },
    "total_count": { "$sum": "$voteCount" }
  }
},
{ "$sort": { "total_count": -1 } }
```

Where I need to insert sort operation, to sort by count in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

To sort an array during aggregation it is a bit tricky stuff.
So what I am duinfg to solve that is:

1. unwinding array
2. apply sort
3. regroup array

please find mongo shell code which will should give an overview ot this technique:

```
var group = {$group:{_id:"$type", votes:{$push:"$value" }}}
var unwind={$unwind:"$votes"}
var sort = {$sort:{"votes":-1}}
var reGroup = {$group:{_id:"$_id", votes:{$push:"$votes" }}}
db.readings.aggregate([group,unwind,sort ,reGroup])
```

any comments welcome!

Comment: I intend to sort by count! can I do var sort = {$sort:{"votes.count":-1}} ??

Comment: @Radiumrasheed: my code snippet is a kind of example - modify and adjust as needed